# Simple Foreach loop with tricky situation

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

I found this problem quite challenging.I have a foreach loop which looks like this.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu1"><a href="#"><?php echo $records[0]['olt_name'] ?></a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <?php
            $unique = array();
            foreach($records as $r)
            {
                $a = substr($r['pon_port'],2,1);
                if(!in_array($a, $unique)) {
                    $unique[] = $a;
                    echo '<li class="menu1"><a href="#">' . $a . '</a>'; //slots
                }

             ------->>>>>> echo '<ul class="menu">';
echo'<li class="menu1"><a href="#">'.substr($r['pon_port'],4,1).'</a></li>';

                        echo '</ul>';
            }

            echo '</li>';
            ?>
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to achieve is a list item like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> Level 1 </a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> Level 1.1 </a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Level 1.1.1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Level 1.1.2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Level 1.1.3 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Level 1.1.4 </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now i facing a tricky situation. The start of `<ul>` which i have shown arrow is looping each time because of foreach. So every time loop runs it goes like this:

```
<ul><li></li><ul> 
<ul><li></li><ul>
```

i dont want `<ul></ul>` to loop every time. Is there a way to enter the `<ul>` once and the donot enter next time the loop runs. only enter `<li>` each time loop runs.

This is dump of $records.

```
array(24) { [0]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/4" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/3" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/1" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/5" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } 
[4]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/2" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } 
[5]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/6" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" } [6]=> array(2) { ["pon_port"]=> string(5) "0/0/7" ["olt_name"]=> string(8) "BRT-OLT1" }
```

Comment: can you show the dump of $records and you expected result? for more understanding

Comment: I don't see why you need `<ul>` in the loop at all. Your desired output just has it before all the `<li>` that are printed by the loop.

Comment: How do you get things like `Level 1.1.1` when you use `substr($r['pon_port'],4,1)`? That should only put one character in the anchor text.

Comment: @karthik N I have updated the question.

Comment: @barmar that is only a format. I want to show only one number. I dont get whats negative marking for? I thought this question was a tricky one and every one would get a chance to learn. Was my question not understandable>>??

Comment: Please format the `var_dump()` readably, not all on one line.

Comment: I'll ask again: why are you echoing `<ul>` in the loop? Just take that out.

Comment: What happened to `class="menu"` and `class="menu1"`? It's in the code, but not in the output.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited var_dump. I have added class menu and menu1 only to style the list item.
All i am asking is how to break from the <ul> tag that i have shown arrow after entering once.

Comment: To make it more clear. Eg: 
foreach($records as $r)
{?>
      <ul>
         <li><?php echo $r; ?><li>
     </ul>
<?php}
I want to enter the <ul> tag just once and enter <li> tag until foreach loop runs. You might say use <ul> tag before foreach loop. But i want a solution where <ul> tag is inside foreach loop. Is there any way??????
?>

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to indicate whether it's the first time through the loop.

```
$unique = array();
$first = true;
foreach ($records as $r) {
    $a = substr($r['pon_port'],2,1);
    if(!in_array($a, $unique)) {
        $unique[] = $a;
        echo '<li class="menu1"><a href="#">' . $a . '</a></li>'; //slots
    }
    if ($first) {
        echo "<ul>";
        $first = false;
    }
    echo'<li class="menu1"><a href="#">'.substr($r['pon_port'],4,1).'</a></li>';
}
if (!$first) {
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ktpaEw)

Comment: sorry it didnt help.

Comment: It Works only if all substr($r['pon_port'],4,1) is 0 . If its value is 1 it doesnot work.
SEE DEMO
http://ideone.com/6yuplO

Comment: What is it supposed to do differently when the value is 1? There's nothing in the question about that.

Comment: BTW, you're missing the `</li>` inside the `if (!in_array)` block. I added that to my answer and made a new demo.